# Define Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define function $J : \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ by the rule $J(r, s) = r+
\sqrt{2}\cdot2s$ for all $(r, s) \in \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}.$

a) Is $J$ one-to-one? Prove or give a counterexample.
b) Is $J$ onto? Prove or give a counterexample

I tired doing it.

for a) I got $r_1 - r_2 = - \sqrt{2} s_1 + -\sqrt{2} s_2\cdots $ I have no idea what to conclude

for b) $J(r,s) = (u,v)$

$r = u - \sqrt{2} s$

$s = (v - r)/\sqrt{2} $

I plugged it back into the original function but it got messy....

Please help

Comment: It would help to use LaTeX as shown at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

For a)
$$r_1 - r_2 = (s_2 - s_1)\sqrt{2},$$
where $r_1,r_2,s_1,s_2$ are all rational. If $s_2 - s_1 \neq 0$, the right-hand side is irrational. But since $r_1,r_2$ are rational, the left hand side is rational. Therefore we must have $s_2 - s_1 = 0$, so $s_1 = s_2$. But then the left hand side must also equal zero, so $r_1 = r_2$. So the $J$ is injective.

I'm not sure what you are trying in b) by setting $J(r,s) = (u,v)$. You are trying to determine whether or not $J$ is onto, i.e. for every real number $x$, are there rational numbers $r,s$ such that $r + s\sqrt{2} = x$? The answer is no. Try to show there are no rational numbers $r,s$ such that $r + s\sqrt{2} = \sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: what i tried to do was something i learnt in school.. So basically what i was thinking that r and s both are irrational numbers so therefore J is not onto.

Comment: $r$ and $s$ are both rational. You defined the domain of $J$ to be $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: but then i showed that r and s are irrational.. I don't know. I'm confused

Comment: Ah ok sorry. You mean you set up an equation $J(r,s) = x$ with $x$ real and found that $r,s$ are irrational? Yeah, that works. The problem with what you wrote is $(u,v)$ is not a real number, it's an ordered pair. Also, you didn't define what $u$ and $v$ are.

Comment: so it's better if i omitted (u,v) and use x? Then it would be r+s√2 = x and solve for both r and s?

Comment: The function is not onto so you have to pick a specific value of $x$ that isn't in the image of $J$ and show that it isn't in the image of $J$. There are lots of choices, like $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\pi$ for example.